# How to exclude the signature and quoted parts from email message using MimeKit?

Tags: .net, email, mimekit, mime-message

Is it possible to detect which parts of the email message are signature and previous messages quoted to this message for excluding those parts, using the MimeKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
static string ExcludeQuotedTextAndSignature (string bodyText)
{
    using (var writer = new StringWriter ()) {
        using (var reader = new StringReader (bodyText)) {
            string line;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine ()) != null) {
                if (line.Length > 0 && line[0] == '>') {
                    // This line is a quoted line, ignore it.
                    continue;
                }

                if (line.Equals ("-- ", StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
                    // This is the start of the signature
                    break;
                }

                writer.WriteLine (line);
            }
        }

        return writer.ToString ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with the HTML part of the body too?

Comment: HTML gets infinitely more interesting. Good luck is all I’ve got to say.

Comment: Dang! Thanks for the tip anyway! :)

Comment: @RojanGh. Did you figure out how to do this for HTML part of body?